# JSTL function escapeXml (List<SelectOption>)

Tags: jstl-functions

```
<div class="width-20">
    <div class="inputBlock clear">
        <label>Select a month: 
            <form:select id="monthSelected" path="month" 
                items="${form.monthList}" itemLabel="label" 
             itemValue="value" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting this error:

`taint_path_call: Form.getMonthList() returns the tainted data.All elements of the collection are considered tainted.This event occurs inside org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.reports.reports_jsp._jspService(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest, javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse), for which no source code was found.`

(#1 of 1): Cross-site scripting (XSS)
5. xss_injection_site: Adding ${form.monthList} to an HTML page allows cross-site scripting, because it was not properly sanitized for context HTML double quoted attribute.

`monthList` is a type of `List<SelectOption>`